# Should I show failed resolution attempts to a problem?

Tags: discussion

Having come from Stackoverflow, I get used to the "rule" that I should always show what I have tried in a question, even if that did not work. Sometimes this might my questions deceitfully longer or harder to tackle than it is really. For example, [my last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088142/why-is-this-a-first-integral-particle-near-schwarzschild-black-hole), the part after the first **boldface** is me trying to resolve the discrepancy the question is about (and the first part of the post). Should I continue doing showing unsuccessful resolution attempts at the cost of making the post lengthy?

Comment: I think that's great. I would appreciate it if you could separate the two parts in case someone wants to try to find a different solution. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! I'll edit it to make the two part more obviously distinct then...

Comment: However I think if you do that there is also a chance that you just get alternative solutions and no one looks at your solution, so I'm not sure what the best way to deal with it is.

Comment: Thank you! Included the separation now, so now hopefully it is better. Split it into 4 parts in the end, hope that's not too many.

Comment: good question, it deserved the 20 upvotes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your linked question is perhaps a little long, but overall it's very good and I wish that more questions looked like this!  I wouldn't change anything about your question -- well, maybe in the spirit of Jorge's comment you could add a separator line after your bolded question to indicate that what is below is not mandatory reading.

Context is critical as it allows answerers to see what you understand and how to pitch an answer, and to some extent it's an indication of good-faith -- by not writing a "Solve my problem" question you're showing that you are interacting with the site in the way that was intended.  This provides good, if lengthy, context, and that's to be applauded.

Comment: Thank you! Just implemented what Jorge has suggested. Ended up splitting it into 4 parts (background, problem, attempted resolution, reapproached question), hope it is not too many.