# New questions are not being added to the community bulletin

Tags: bug, community-bulletin

A meta question is eligible to appear in [community bulletin](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-bulletin/info) if it is less than two weeks old, has score $\ge3$ and is tagged [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion).

There are several questions posted recently which fulfill the criteria, but are not shown in the community bulletin. (And the time period seems to be too long to blame this on caching.) Some examples:

- [A specific confusing MathJax syntax that works randomly or not](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33354/a-specific-confusing-mathjax-syntax-that-works-randomly-or-not)
- [Mathjax syntaxes that don't look very good?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33366/mathjax-syntaxes-that-dont-look-very-good)
- [I am a student and have reached my limit of 50 questions per month what do I do?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33367/i-am-a-student-and-have-reached-my-limit-of-50-questions-per-month-what-do-i-do)
- [If I recognize the source of someone's question, should I edit to add it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33402/if-i-recognize-the-source-of-someones-question-should-i-edit-to-add-it)
- [Should I show failed resolution attempts to a problem?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33407/should-i-show-failed-resolution-attempts-to-a-problem)
- [Tag synonym, Name change and Reuse proposal for "norm"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33409/tag-synonym-name-change-and-reuse-proposal-for-norm)

The only questions I see among Hot Meta Posts is "[Scaling down large images in posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33346)" - this one was posted on March 24. (So in a few days it will no longer fulfill the criteria to be selected.)

Why did this happen? Do other sites have the same problem? Could this be corrected?

Here is a screenshot (I have included also the question, so that you can see when the screenshot was taken).

[image: screenshot]

I have searched a bit to see whether some similar bug report was posted on other metas, I have seen a post on Stack Overflow Meta from January 2021: [What happened to Hot Meta Posts again?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404382)

Comment: I will add that I got a brief response [from Catija in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8816273#8816273). (From that message it seems that the plan might be to show also feature requests. The post which is now shown in the CB has both tags, discussion and feature-request.)

Comment: This post on Meta Stack Overflow is related to the changes mentioned above: [Feature non-\[discussion\] meta post in the community bulletin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404398#406461).

Comment: Feature requests are being featured, however. Tag this as [feature-request] to demonstrate.

Comment: Does this mean that the "hot meta posts" will show only those posts which have both these tags "discussion" and "feature request"? It should work as a union of these tags and not as intersection.

Comment: @Braiam didn't work. I still see only one link in CB. Martin: you mentioned that it was both discussion and feature-request, perhaps with the discussion tag might work.

Comment: @Verónica yeah, it needs to be both fr and discussion https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362932/213575

Comment: I quote from Braiam’s link: “ Looks like the API Docs confirm that adding multiple tags counts as an "and" rather than an "or", so Adam is going to roll this back in the short term until we can figure out the correct solution. – Catija♦ 6 hours ago”